# MYSQL Syntax error for Insert / Update query linked to a secondary table

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a query which is suppose to either update or insert based upon whether the row exists.

I then also connect it to a secondary table so i can link them on the correct id's but im getting a syntax error and am unsure how to fix it.

This is my query:

```
INSERT INTO resources as r (r.quantity,r.tid)
  SELECT r.quantity+?,u.tid                                             
    FROM users u WHERE u.uid = ? 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
   r.quantity = r.quantity+?, r.tid = u.tid
```

The error is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to use near 'as r (r.quantity,r.tid) SELECT 
r.quantity+'0',u.tid FR' at line 1
```

Any one able to explain the what I have misunderstood and how i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `insert` statement doesn't take aliases.  I think you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO resources(quantity, tid)
    SELECT ?, u.tid                                             
    FROM users u
    WHERE u.uid = ? 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY
        UPDATE quantity = quantity+?
```

Comment: What about the link between the two tables `r.tid = u.tid` ?